# execute strings javascript without eval (alternative)

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm in a dev console and was asking myself is there a way to execute encrypted text without using eval?

example with eval:

```js
let encrypted = 'Y29uc29sZS5sb2coJ3Rlc3QnKQ==' // (console.log('test') as base64)
eval(window.atob(encrypted))
```

so could I do that without eval?

Comment: You can use the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) constructor. [Never use `eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Comment: @jabaa what do you mean?

Comment: I posted two links. Open them. You usually don't need `eval` and you should not use it.

Comment: The function constructor isn't much better, though at least it doesn't give access to the scope of the callsite.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts And it has better performance.

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` both accept stringified code for their first parameter.  Definitely a bad practice though

Comment: By the way, `encrytped` is misleading because there's no key. Base64 is an encoding, not an encryption.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `eval` in this case?

Comment: @jabaa Except when it's the right tool, of course :-) OP mentions working in the devtools console, and in that case simplicity might be more important than encapsulation.

Comment: @Bergi Of course. Somehow I didn't process this information.